# Php Average of Multiple Times

Tags: php, time, average

When i tried to get avarage of multiple times of array,its return the false value to me while array has two different day time.For example;

When the times be like :  23:30:30 - 01:30:30 Average should be : 00:30:30

But now it returns : 12:30:30

**My Array:**

```
    [0] => 22:50:20
    [1] => 05:37:42
    [2] => 04:21:15
    [3] => 02:51:00
    [4] => 00:35:09
    [5] => 01:28:45
    [6] => 23:15:47
    [7] => 02:50:01
    [8] => 03:32:04
    [9] => 00:09:17
    [10] => 23:49:10
    [11] => 23:26:37
    [12] => 00:35:56
    [13] => 04:54:00
    [14] => 00:55:06
    [15] => 23:32:03
    [16] => 02:27:27
    [17] => 02:22:42
    [18] => 01:49:47
    [19] => 03:25:36 ) 


    Average: 07:44:29
```

**Php Code**

```
date('h:i:s', array_sum(array_map('strtotime', $all_times)) / count($all_times));
```

Comment: It's the correct time, but you're displaying it in 12 hour format. Try using H:i:s instead

Comment: I don't see how that's wrong, it seems you are adding and getting the average of this durations

Comment: The way you're calculating it, the average of 23:30pm and 01:30am is going to be 12:30pm (i.e. half way between them on the same day). If you want a different value, you need to include dates.

Comment: *"23:30:30 - 01:30:30 Average should be : 00:30:30"* -- the average is `12:30:30`. It is `00:30:30` only if `01:30:30` is on the next day but this information is not provided anywhere in your input data.

Comment: You need a absolute base, your each time have a ralative base. Only in the same base your average will be reasonable.

Comment: Main problem is average should be between max(05:37:42) and min(22:50:20).But when i tried get average of that values,it returns other side of day.

Comment: But 22:50:20 isn't lower than 05:37:42 unless they're on different days, and your code doesn't specify that.

Comment: Actually it is low,im taking that values like min value 22:00:00 and max 6:00.00 it has to compare that values between that scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going from your last comment, you need to treat all times between **22:00** and **23:59** as the previous day, so that you're averaging values across a single continuous six-hour period, rather than a 24-hour day. You can do this by subtracting a day from all values where the time is later than 10pm:

```
$times = ['23:00', '01:00'];

$total = 0;

foreach ($times as $time) {
    $dt = new DateTime($time);

    // Treat all values later than 10pm as the previous day
    if ($dt->format('H') >= 22) {
        $dt->modify('-1 day');
    }

    // Sum the timestamps
    $total += $dt->format('U');
}

$average = $total / count ($times);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $average);

// 2017-11-08 00:00:00
```

See https://eval.in/895375